# How do I fix an HTML panel to the page after it hits the top of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a social media panel that sits next to the title of a blog post (about 200px or so from the top of the viewport) and when the user scrolls down the page I want the panel to have a fixed position only when the top of the social panel hits the top of the viewport. An example of what I'm trying to do is any post on Mashable's website, for instance:  http://mashable.com/2011/12/05/facetones/. Notice how the social media panel on the left of the content panel scrolls with the page until it hits the top of the browser viewport, and then it becomes fixed. Any tutorial explaining how to do this with pure CSS or (better yet) jQuery would be greatly helpful, as I was not able to find anything myself. I guess I just didn't even know how to start searching for such a thing.

Currently I have figured out how to setup my HTML/CSS to display the social media panel fixed to the page beside the content panel and it works perfectly, but I'd like for it to scroll up with the page and THEN become fixed when it hits the top of the viewport as mentioned above, instead of staying fixed exactly to the page without scrolling at all as my code currently does. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed">

    <div id="sharebox-wrapper">

        <div id="sharebox">

            <div class="inner">

                share

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fixed {position:fixed;}
#sharebox-wrapper {position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;}
#sharebox {width:100px;background:#F3F3F3 url(images/sharebox-bg.png) repeat-y right 0px;border:1px solid #CFCFCF;border-right:0px;position:absolute;left:-116px;top:25px;height:400px;}
#sharebox .inner {padding:12px;}
```

Comment: _"how to do this with pure CSS or (better yet) jQuery"_ - why is pure CSS not your preferred option?

Comment: It would be neat if the social media box was able to scroll down in a jquery animated fashion once it hits the top of the page, instead of just fixing itself using standard CSS. I guess I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really pretty simple. Create a class that describes the fixed positioning. Monitor the scroll event of the window. If the top of the social media are going to go off screen, switch it to fixed. If not, let it position itself normally. I just wrote this, but it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpErD/1/

```
var mediaTop = $('div#sharebox-wrapper').offset().top; 
var media = $('div#sharebox-wrapper');

$(document).scroll( function() {
   var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

   //fix/unfix as necessary
   if (mediaTop < scrollTop) {
       $(media).addClass('fixed'); 
   }
   else { 
       $(media).removeClass('fixed'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: I would say the only other thing to consider with this is to make sure that the parent container does not shift height when #socialmedia is switched to position fixed since the height of that element will be reduced from the parent when it is pulled out.

Comment: So what would the html look like, based on my html posted above? Would the div element with the fixed class be nested inside of the div element with the socialmedia id? I can't get this to work and I'm not sure how to setup the html... thanks!

Comment: @brianmcculloh - It probably didn't work right because you have relative positioning on the container by ID. Therefore adding a class to toggle fixed state work because ID's take precedence over classes in CSS. I cleaned up the code a little and posted a working example for you.

Comment: I figured out why it's not working. I'm absolutely positioning it so it sits 100px to the left of my main content window, so when I add the  fixed class to the outer wrapper it screws up the absolute positioning of the inner wrapper. Check out the modified example to get an idea of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/zpErD/1/

Comment: I was able to get even further. I just can't figure out why, when changing the class of a container from absolute to fixed, it disregards the outer container's left attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/brianmcculloh/B9RV7/2/ - so close!

Comment: When you change the absolutely positioned elements class to fixed it pulls it out of main, which causes main to collapse. It also means the left property does not use main, it uses the main document window. So the sidebar flies off the left hand edge of the page. If you really want this structure you may want to change the 'top' css value to be the scrollTop and not bother with fixed at all.

Comment: Figured it out. I put a margin-left:-100px in the .fixed class and it worked perfectly. Now to test on other browsers, fingers crossed...