# How to create a page that has a right column which should not scroll after some point

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you look at this page,

http://www.cracked.com/blog/4-simple-pieces-career-advice-almost-no-one-follows/

you will see that after scrolling down a few pages, the right column gets fixed on the last part and does not get scrolled down with the rest of the page.(it si fixed on the last ad)
How can i accomplish this effect? is there a tutorial or guide for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate/The accepted answer to this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395067/how-do-i-fix-an-html-panel-to-the-page-after-it-hits-the-top-of-the-viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery. If .box is the div you want fixed after scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop > 200){
        $('.box').css('position','fixed');
        }
});
```

Comment: Well, it's not really a "need" to use jQuery, since this could be achieved with JavaScript. I mean, if he uses anyway ok, but an entire library just for this its a bit… mrfff.